# No route matches "/application" with {:method=>:get}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having exactly the same problem as in this threat

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=139352#p139352

but unfortunately, the solution is not specified...

My SO is Ubuntu 10.10
My apache server is integrated on xampp1.7.4
Rails 2.3.5

I am getting the error when I am at http://localhost:3000/application

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/application" with {:method=>:get}):
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/routing/recognition_optimisation.rb:66:in `recognize_path'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:441:in `recognize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/handler/webrick.rb:48:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
```

**EDIT**  route.rb

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   map.connect 'products/:id', :controller => 'catalog', :action => 'view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   map.purchase 'products/:id/purchase', :controller => 'catalog', :action => 'purchase'
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   map.resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   map.resources :products, :member => { :short => :get, :toggle => :post }, :collection => { :sold => :get }

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   map.resources :products, :has_many => [ :comments, :sales ], :has_one => :seller

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   map.resources :products do |products|
  #     products.resources :comments
  #     products.resources :sales, :collection => { :recent => :get }
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     admin.resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with map.root -- just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # map.root :controller => "welcome"

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # Install the default routes as the lowest priority.
  # Note: These default routes make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests. You should
  # consider removing or commenting them out if you're using named routes and resources.
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @BlancaHdez That link does not go to any question (at least when you aren't logged into that site). Don't know what the context of the question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is exactly what the error dumps says. You only have two things mapped, and neither of them will match `/application`.

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

Will only match things like

```
  `/posts/show/1`
  `/pages/edit/4.html`
```

You need to add a route which will point to the action on your `ApplicationController`

Comment: It should be noted that routing directly to ApplicationController is discouraged. Since it's often used as a repository for "helper-like" methods (current_user, etc.), it can be very easy to accidentally expose something you didn't mean to.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how routes.rb is built, and how to use it. I found several tutorials, but none of them very clear. Could somebody advise me a good one? Thanks